# Get All Users with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_chat_messages` (
  `cmid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `from_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `to_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `chat_message` text NOT NULL,
  `offer_mesage` text NOT NULL,
  `message_type` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT '0 = text 1 = image 2= offer',
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT '0 = not read 1 = read'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `tbl_chat_messages` (`cmid`, `from_user_id`, `to_user_id`, `chat_message`, `offer_mesage`, `message_type`, `timestamp`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 5, 1, 'Hello Rajubhai', '', 0, '2022-03-21 22:46:29', 0);

CREATE TABLE `tbl_users` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `full_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `profile_image` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default.png',
  `online` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `current_session` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `connection_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `connected_with` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `tbl_users` (`id`, `username`, `full_name`, `profile_image`, `online`, `current_session`, `connection_id`, `connected_with`) VALUES
(1, 'user1', 'USER 1', 'default.png', 0, 0, '', 0),
(2, 'user2', 'USER 2', 'default.png', 0, 0, '', 0),
(3, 'user3', 'USER 3', 'default.png', 0, 0, '', 0),
(4, 'user4', 'USER 4', 'default.png', 0, 0, '', 0),
(5, 'user5', 'USER 5', 'default.png', 0, 0, '', 0);
```

I am looking to get a list of all users who have talked before to each other or have sent message to each other.

For now I have 1 record in `tbl_chat_messages` sent from_user_id = 5 and to_user_id = 1.

So I need to get two users called user 1 and user 5 with my query but its giving me only one user called 5. My query is like below

```
SELECT u.id,
       u.username,
       u.profile_image,
       u.connected_with,
       u.online,
      (    SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM tbl_chat_messages
           WHERE to_user_id = 5
           AND from_user_id = u.id
           AND status = 5
      ) AS count_status
FROM `tbl_chat_messages` AS m
         LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS u ON m.from_user_id = u.id
WHERE m.from_user_id = 5
  OR  m.to_user_id = 5
GROUP BY u.id
```

**Actual Result:**

| id | username | profile_image | connected_with | online | count_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | user5 | default.png | 0 | 0 | 0 |

**Expected Result**

| id | username | profile_image | connected_with | online | count_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | user5 | default.png | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | user1 | default.png | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Let me know if anyone can help me for correct my query.

> GOAL : If I am user1, When My Chat Page Load, I want get user list who
> have sent me message before or I have sent message before instead List
> of all users.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please take a minute to post the table structure (CREATE TABLE...), some sample data (INSERT statements) and the expected results based on the sample data - all as text, not screen shots.

Comment: m.from_user_id = 5 OR m.to_user_id = 5 <---- maybe change m.to_user_id = 1

Comment: @SOS I have added structure of both table and data

Comment: @user2260040 its not making any difference

Comment: What are your expected results? Post it in table format as an [edit]

Comment: @SOS I have added Goal in end of question. May be its clear my requirement. Thanks

Comment: It's still a little unclear, but I will say the JOIN needs to include both from/to user columns https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1a2d5dac31248851b2dc26c84d4eaec0

Comment: @SOS Its working fine. I just have added GROP BY u.id to avoid multiple record of same user. You can post it as Answer and I am happy to upvote and accept it as answer. Thanks!

Comment: SELECT u.id, u.username, u.profile_image, u.connected_with,u.online FROM `tbl_chat_messages` m, tbl_users u where m.from_user_id = u.id and m.from_user_id = 5 UNION SELECT u1.id, u1.username, u1.profile_image, u1.connected_with,u1.online FROM `tbl_chat_messages` m, tbl_users u1 where m.to_user_id = u1.id and m.to_user_id = 1;

Comment: Try this version.  Removed the hard coded id's and used a conditional sum instead of a subquery https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=84d2ec2afc274d1c2614950a84d468ee

Comment: @SOS actually status column in message table is used for message read status, its value 0 is for unread and 1 is for read

Comment: Oh okay, `status = 5`, is in the original question, but it can be changed to whatever value is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JOIN needs to include both the `from_user_id` and `to_user_id` columns. Also, try a conditional SUM() instead of a subquery. For example, if `5` is the current user id:

```
SELECT u.id
      , u.username
      , u.profile_image
      , u.connected_with
      , u.online
      , SUM( IF(m.status = 0, 1, 0) ) AS count_unread
FROM tbl_chat_messages AS m 
         LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS u 
         ON m.from_user_id = u.id
         OR m.to_user_id = u.id
WHERE m.from_user_id = 5
OR    m.to_user_id = 5
GROUP BY u.id
```

**Results:**

| id | username | profile_image | connected_with | online | count_unread |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | user5 | default.png | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | user1 | default.png | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: Thanks a lot! Its working like charm!